# Calculate time difference in seconds in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame with a datetime column ('time') in m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss format.  I need to calculate the difference between each row and the previous row and display the result in a new column ('SEC') in seconds.

For example:

```
time                    SEC
4/18/2023 2:43:00       
4/18/2023 3:13:00       1800
4/18/2023 3:35:53       1373
4/18/2023 3:36:03       10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `diff` + `.dt.total_seconds` (ty @QuangHoang)

```
df['time'].diff().dt.total_seconds
```

If your `time` column is not yet a `datetime64` dtype, you can do

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df['time'].diff().dt.total_seconds
```